# Reduce with Integer domain, but receive a rational solution

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

**Bug introduced in 6.0 and fixed in 10.0**

---

I want to find the integer values $k$ so that `D[f[x], x]` has integer solutions. I tried

```
f[x_] := 2 x^3 - 3 (m - 1) x^2 + k * (m + 2)*(m - 3) x + 1
g := D[f[x], x]
d = Discriminant[g, x]
Reduce[{d == 0, -10 <= k <= 10}, {k, m}, Integers]
```

I got

```
(m == -3 && k == 4) || (m == 1 && k == 0) || (m == 7 && k == 3/2)
```

As you can see in the last solution `k=3/2` which is definitely not an integer, as I have specified in the domain used by `Reduce`.

Is this a bug? Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: You appear to have two negative signs in your definition of `f[x]`.  In any case, I tried both $(m-1)$ and $(m+1)$, copied directly from your code, and I did NOT get your results.  What version are you using?  I am using 9.0.1.  Oh, and what was your value of the discriminant?  I got $d = 6912000 (-1 + m)^3 (-6 k - k m + k m^2)^3$ for $(m-1)$.

Comment: I am not using 9.0.1

Comment: I need more information.  What is the correct form for `f[x]`?  Which version of Mathematica are you running?  What is the value of $d$ that you obtained from your code?  If you want help, you need to tell us more.

Comment: My version of Mathematica is 9.0.0. I obtained d is -12 (-3 - 12 k + 6 m - 2 k m - 3 m^2 + 2 k m^2). I edited `f[x]`.

Comment: Now our outputs match exactly.  This is very curious behavior and I think it's safe to say that it is a bug, because `Reduce[]` should never return a solution that is not an integer when an integer domain is specified.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. From the documentation: "If dom is Reals, or a subset such as Integers or Rationals, then all constants and function values are also restricted to be real."

Comment: @rasher I think this is only formulated badly in the documentation. The line directly above in the details section states *Reduce[expr,vars,dom] restricts all variables and parameters to belong to the domain dom.* which clearly is what I would expect `Reduce` to do, when I specify the domain.

Comment: @halirutan: Perhaps, though by my interpretation of the docs, k here is neither - it is a constant. Perhaps a Wolfram staff member or another local wizard can comment.

Comment: I agree with @halirutan, since the OP explicitly declares `m` and `k` to be variables.  Note partial back-substitution yields `False`: Try either `Reduce[{(d /. m -> 7) == 0, -10 <= k <= 10}, k, Integers]` or `Reduce[{d == 0, m == 7, -10 <= k <= 10}, k, Integers]`.  (However, Diophantos himself routinely gave rational solutions to his problems.)

Comment: If you apply `Reduce[output, {m, k}, Integers]` to the OP's output, the extraneous solution goes away.

Comment: I can reproduce the OP's result.  I think this is a bug because `Reduce[d == 0 && -10 <= k <= 10 && k \[Element] Integers && 
  m \[Element] Integers, {k, m}]` gives the same `k==3/2` result ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug.

The following also gives non-integer solutions which is clearly incorrect.

```
Reduce[d == 0 && -10 <= k <= 10 && k \[Element] Integers && m \[Element] Integers, {k, m}]
```

Comment: This is so that the question gets off the unanswered list and Community stops bumping it up.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer but may aid the discussion, the problem arises with the more simple form:

```
p = RandomInteger[100];
q = RandomInteger[{2, 100}];
Reduce[{k == p/q ( m^2 - 2 m + 1)/(m^2 - m - 6) , m > 4 }, {k, m},   Integers]
```

Produces the anomolous result `m==7,k==p/q`  for "many" values of p,q.

Anyone arguing that k is somehow not supposed to be restricted needs to explain why there is just the one odd result, where obviously there is a rational k for any integer m (except 3,-2 of course)..

Comment: No need for any dispute, it's been recognized as a bug.